# Convert Adobe Flash CS5 file to Adobe Flash CS3

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I have Adobe Flash CS5 file named bannerCS5.fla, how can I convert it to Adobe Flash CS3 file ?
When I googled, I heard it is impossible to do so. 
I tried the following alternative,

1. Installed Adobe Flash CS5 30 days trial
2. Tried to save bannerCS5.fla as Adobe Flash CS4 file. But I could not do that. The application quits now.

If I could do the second step, I would open the CS4 file in Flash CS4 and then use 'Save as' Flash CS3 Document.

Any workarounds ?

Comment: That's the only method you described, AFAIK: there's only one-version backward compatibility in Flash products and there's no side tools.